# How to set Postgresql database to see date as "MDY" permanently

Tags: postgresql, date-format

How can I set my database to see the 'date' as "MDY" without running:

```
SET datestyle = "ISO, MDY";
```

every-time I'm trying to access it?
I'm using Postgresql version 9.1, Ubuntu 12.04.
My system locale, at the time of the database installation was set to `en_CA.utf8` and I recently changed it to `en_US.utf8`.

```
show lc_CTYPE
```

returns: --> `"en_CA.UTF-8"`

but

```
show LC_CoLLATE
```

returns: --> `"en_CA.UTF-8"`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I used to have a very similar problem years ago, and then discovered that I can do

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET datestyle TO "ISO, MDY";
```

Try that.  (This works on a per database basis. For a solution for all of your databases, set this parameter in your `postgresql.conf` - thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name.)

Please be aware that the default setting is [not locale independent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE).  However, after `initdb` sets it to whatever it wants, you can change it yourself in the `postgresql.conf`.

@swasheck's comment made me note that with my settings:

```
test=# SHOW lc_ctype;
      lc_ctype
--------------------
 Hungarian, Hungary
(1 row)


test=# SHOW lc_time;
      lc_time
--------------------
 Hungarian, Hungary
(1 row)
```

setting `datestyle` has the following effect:

```
SET datestyle TO "ISO, MDY";

SELECT current_date;
    date
------------
 2012-06-21
(1 row)
```

Now this is not really expected - and it's the same on another server with `en_US.UTF8`, too.  Trying `"ISO, DMY"`, too suggests me that the `"ISO"` part is more or less overriding the other part when producing an **output**.  For **input** values, it has the expected effect, as summarized in the table below:

```
                          input values
           '2016/01/21'   '01/21/2016'   '21/01/2016'         output
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
ISO, YMD        OK             --             --            2016-01-21
ISO, DMY        --             OK             --            2016-01-21
ISO, MDY        --             --             OK            2016-01-21
```

`--` above means that the given input style results in an error for the given `datestyle` setting.

Upon careful reading of the documentation, one can see that `datestyle` is a pair of partially conflicting settings:

> For historical reasons, this variable contains two independent components: the output format specification (ISO, Postgres, SQL, or German) and the input/output specification for year/month/day ordering (DMY, MDY, or YMD).

For me, it means that one has to find the one that fits their needs by a bit of experimenting - but the best way is to leave it at the default and always use an unambiguous input format.  Two of these are `'YYYY-MM-DD'` and `'YYYYMMDD'`.  I prefer the former - even using this IRL ;)

Note: the `datestyle` setting (and other runtime settings) from `postgresql.conf` can be overridden by an `ALTER DATABASE bla SET datestyle ...`, setting it permanently for a single database, or by `SET datestyle TO ...` setting it for the current session.  This latter might be useful when importing some third party data with a different date format.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks ***@a_horse_with_no_name| @dezso | @ypercubeᵀᴹ***

### I want to write answer thats **simple to implement : Steps**

> **Way 1** : *setting datestyle Per Database Only*

1. `show datestyle;` show you current date style **"ISO, DMY**" or **"ISO, MDY"**
2. Now depending on what you want in postgres  **DMY** or **MDY** set in below query

   `ALTER DATABASE "my_database_name" SET datestyle TO "ISO, DMY";`

   or

   `ALTER DATABASE "my_database_name" SET datestyle TO "ISO, MDY";`
3. Most important step : **Always after setting datestyle restart postgres**

   `sudo service postgresql restart`

   Or

   `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`
4. Lets test configuration

   if you have set **DMY** below query should work for you

   **Query:**`select '20/12/2016'::date`  **Output:**  `"2016-12-20"`

   **Or**

   if you have set **MDY** below query should work for you

   **Query:**`select '12/19/2016'::date`  **Output:**  `"2016-12-19"`

> **Way 2** : Permanently : *whatever you set in config file will be set in all databases you will create in future*

1. In /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf set

   `datestyle = 'iso, dmy'` OR `datestyle = 'iso, mdy'`
2. Most important step : **Always after setting datestyle restart postgres**

   `sudo service postgresql restart`

   Or

   `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`
3. Lets test configuration

   if you have set **DMY** below query should work for you

   **Query:**`select '20/12/2016'::date`  **Output:**  `"2016-12-20"`

   **Or**

   if you have set **MDY** below query should work for you

   **Query:**`select '12/19/2016'::date`  **Output:**  `"2016-12-19"`

Answer (score 0):

Expanding [@deszo's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/19681/242172) answer (I do not have enough reputation to comment there), `ISO` parameter overrides the day-month-year specification in output. **If you want to have input and output in the same format**, you need to use `SET DATESTYLE TO 'SQL, MDY'`, or `SET DATESTYLE TO 'MDY, SQL'` (parameter order is inferred by Postgres).