# date/time field value out of range: "21/1/2016"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, datetime, date

My PostgreSQL database version is

PostgreSQL 9.3.10 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit

**In both databases**, datestyle is set to`"ISO, DMY"`.

---

### ATTEMPT 1

**Query :**

```
insert into station(name , date) values('test' , '21/1/2016')
```

**Error Log:**

```
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "21/1/2016"
LINE 1: select '21/1/2016'::date
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.

********** Error **********

ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "21/1/2016"
SQL state: 22008
Hint: Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
Character: 8
```

### ATTEMPT 2

**Query :**

```
select '21/1/2016'::date
```

**Error log :**

```
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "21/1/2016"
LINE 1: select '21/1/2016'::date
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.

********** Error **********

ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "21/1/2016"
SQL state: 22008
Hint: Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
Character: 8
```

On one system it works and on other system it doesn't. Both have Ubuntu and the same PostgreSQL version.

**COLLATE SETTINGS ON BOTH SERVERS**

> Query **works** successfuly on this server and has below COLLATE setting

```
show lc_CTYPE   -> C
show LC_CoLLATE -> C
SHOW lc_time;   -> "en_IN"
select '21/1/2016'::date   -> "2016-01-21"
```

> Query **Does not Works** on this server and has below COLLATE setting

```
show lc_CTYPE  -> "en_IN"
show LC_CoLLATE ->  "en_IN"
SHOW lc_time -> "en_IN"
select '21/1/2016'::date  -> above error log
```

Comment: Just use a sane format, like `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `'YYYYMMDD'`, everywhere?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ i want to use day month year DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: Actually, your values are formatted with `DD/M/YYYY`, not with `DD-MM-YYYY`.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thanks , you were right also i wrote here [new detailed answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19679/how-to-set-postgresql-database-to-see-date-as-mdy-permanently) just right now